# iOS - What is the allocations leak?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have profiled one of my apps using Allocations, and find that whenever I call a particular method my amount of "Live Bytes" increases by 300 KB.  I have no idea what could be causing this.

The following line of code is the culprit:

```
CNTile *newTile = [self getTileAtPosition:3];
```

The associated method reads like this:

```
- (CNTile *)getTileAtPosition:(int)pos
{
    CNTile *tileToReturn;

    for (int x = 0; x < [row count]; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < [col count]; y++)
        {
            The code here generates four CGPoints and a CGMutablePathRef,
            then uses CGPathContainsPoint to determine which CNTile to return.
        }
    }

    return tileToReturn;
}
```

I should mention that my `CNTile` class contains only a `UIView` and `UIImageView`, as well as a few simple variables (such as `int`s and `BOOL`s).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it's not an issue to have your Live Bytes increased (in a reasonable measure of course), as long as they are correctly deallocated afterwards. For example, if the Live Bytes increase when you load a ViewController, if you leave this ViewController and come back to it, you should see the same amount of live bytes (for example, 50KB before, 300KB when you load, goes down when you leave, back to 300KB when you come back). **Not 100% sure of this, but that's what I remember of my profiling experience..**

Comment: Please post the code for the inner "for" loop - it's the critical area. Also, does the number of live bytes remain the same after a while or does it drop back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you create `CGMutablePathRef`? With `CGPathCreateMutable`? If yes, make sure you use `CGPathRelease` to release it:

```
CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
...
CGPathRelease(thePath);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think either the `CGPoints` or `CGMutablePathRef` would be the problem because I thought they would involve such a small number of bytes, but this seems to have fixed the problem! I had only closed the path, not released it.

Comment: Well, two loops may increase memory consumption drastically :)